# Using a PropertyGrid to input method parameters

Tags: c#

I'd like to use a PropertyGrid to input method parameters.

I have some application that will dynamically load user's DLLs and invoke methods with specific signature (a known return type).

I'd like to present the user the option to input the arguments to the called method easily with a PropertyGrid control.

Problem is -- PropertyGrid works on an Object, and not on a method.

I'd like to somehow "transform" the method at runtime into an object with properties reflecting its arguments, passing the input values to the method when invoking it.

Offcourse i'd like to have type validation, etc (if provided by the PropertyGrid, dont remember right now).

Is there any easy solution for this?

Thanks!

Comment: I've fired up LinqPad and built a sample using CodeDom, but I don't feel like posting this for someone with that kind of attitude. (I'm not after the points, just feels wrong..)

Comment: are u referring to my attitude? i am new here and i didnt know that i need to mark it as accepted. I marked few answers as "Accepted" but this still didnt update here. I am sorry for the trouble

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well here is what I've written yesterday.
It is meant to be run in [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net), which is an awesome free tool to test linq queries or code snippets. (With an inexpensive upgrade to get intellisense)

The code should tell you how to deal with different kind of parameters (ref, out) and whether you are calling an instance method or not. (flip the comments in Main to test an instance method)

In LinqPad, you can use the Dump() extension method to let it show your objects in the results window. this is handy to see what is actually happening.

So, if you want to know how to dynamically construct a type and invoke it, this should get you started:

***EDIT: I totally forgot to mention, that you do need to add these 2 namespaces to the query. You do that by hitting F4->additional namespace imports and adding these 2:*

System.CodeDom.Compiler

System.CodeDom**

```
public static String TestMethod1(int a, ref int X, out string t)
{
    a += X;
    X = a * 2;
    t = "...>" + (X + a);
    return a.ToString() + "...";
}

public class TestClass
{
    public int SomeMethod(int a, DateTime? xyz)
    {
      if(xyz != null)
            a+= xyz.GetValueOrDefault().Day;
        return 12 + a;
    }
}

void Main()
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    var methodInfo = typeof(UserQuery).GetMethod("TestMethod1");

    dynamic instance = CreateWrapper(methodInfo, sb);

    instance.a = 11;
    instance.X = 2;

    instance.CallMethod();

    /*
    var methodInfo = typeof(TestClass).GetMethod("SomeMethod");

    dynamic instance = CreateWrapper(methodInfo, sb);

    instance.a = 11;
    instance.xyz = new DateTime(2010, 1, 2);

    instance.CallMethod(new TestClass());
*/
    ((Object)instance).Dump();

    sb.ToString().Dump();
}

static object CreateWrapper(MethodInfo methodInfo, StringBuilder sb)
{
  // pick either C#, VB or another language that can handle generics
    var codeDom = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("C#");

    var unit = new CodeCompileUnit();
    var codeNameSpace = new CodeNamespace();
    codeNameSpace.Name = "YourNamespace";
    var wrapperType = AddWrapperType(codeDom, codeNameSpace, methodInfo, "WrapperType",     "MethodResultValue");

    unit.Namespaces.Add(codeNameSpace);

    // this is only needed so that LinqPad can dump the code
    codeDom.GenerateCodeFromNamespace(codeNameSpace, new StringWriter(sb), new CodeGeneratorOptions());

    // put the temp assembly in LinqPad's temp folder
    var outputFileName = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(new Uri(typeof(UserQuery).Assembly.CodeBase).AbsolutePath), 
                                                                      Guid.NewGuid() + ".dll");
    var results = codeDom.CompileAssemblyFromDom(new CompilerParameters(new[]{new Uri(methodInfo.DeclaringType.Assembly.CodeBase).AbsolutePath,
                                                                              new Uri(typeof(UserQuery).Assembly.CodeBase).AbsolutePath,
                                                                              new Uri(typeof(UserQuery).BaseType.Assembly.CodeBase).AbsolutePath}.Distinct().ToArray(),
                                                                                                                                                        outputFileName), 
                                                                                             unit);
    results.Errors.Dump();
    new Uri(results.CompiledAssembly.CodeBase).AbsolutePath.Dump();

    if(results.Errors.Count == 0)
    {
        var compiledType = results.CompiledAssembly.GetType(codeNameSpace.Name + "." + wrapperType.Name);

        return Activator.CreateInstance(compiledType);
    }
    return null;
}


static CodeTypeDeclaration AddWrapperType(CodeDomProvider codeDom, 
                                          CodeNamespace codeNameSpace, 
                                                                                    MethodInfo methodInfo, 
                                                                                    string typeName, 
                                                                                    string resultPropertyName)
{
    var parameters = (from parameter in methodInfo.GetParameters()
                      select parameter).ToList();

    var returnValue = methodInfo.ReturnType;

    if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(methodInfo.DeclaringType.Namespace))
        codeNameSpace.Imports.Add(new CodeNamespaceImport(methodInfo.DeclaringType.Namespace));

    var wrapperType = new CodeTypeDeclaration(typeName);

    var defaultAttributes = MemberAttributes.Public | MemberAttributes.Final;
    var thisRef = new CodeThisReferenceExpression();

    Func<Type, Type> getRealType = t => t.IsByRef || t.IsPointer ? t.GetElementType(): t;


    Func<String, String> getFieldName = parameterName => "m_" + parameterName + "_Field";


    Action<ParameterInfo> addProperty = p =>
    {
        var realType = getRealType(p.ParameterType);
        var usedName = p.Position == -1 ? resultPropertyName : p.Name;

        wrapperType.Members.Add(new CodeMemberField
        {
            Name = getFieldName(usedName),
            Type = new CodeTypeReference(realType),
            Attributes= MemberAttributes.Private
        });

        var property = new CodeMemberProperty
                                        {
                                            Name = usedName,
                                            Type = new CodeTypeReference(realType),
                                          Attributes= defaultAttributes
                                        };

        property.GetStatements.Add(new CodeMethodReturnStatement(new CodeFieldReferenceExpression(thisRef,  
                                                                                                  getFieldName(usedName))));
        property.SetStatements.Add(new CodeAssignStatement(new CodeFieldReferenceExpression(thisRef,  getFieldName(usedName)), 
                                                           new CodeArgumentReferenceExpression("value")));

        wrapperType.Members.Add(property);
    };

    parameters.ForEach(addProperty);
    if(methodInfo.ReturnParameter != null)
    {
        addProperty(methodInfo.ReturnParameter);
    }

    var callMethod = new CodeMemberMethod
    {
        Name="CallMethod", 
        Attributes=defaultAttributes
    };

    CodeMethodInvokeExpression invokeExpr;

    if(!methodInfo.IsStatic)
    {
        callMethod.Parameters.Add(new CodeParameterDeclarationExpression(methodInfo.DeclaringType, 
                                                                         "instance"));
        invokeExpr = new CodeMethodInvokeExpression(new CodeArgumentReferenceExpression("instance"),
                                                    methodInfo.Name);
    }
    else
        invokeExpr = new CodeMethodInvokeExpression(new CodeTypeReferenceExpression(methodInfo.DeclaringType), methodInfo.Name);

    foreach(var parameter in parameters)
    {
        CodeExpression fieldExpression = new CodeFieldReferenceExpression(thisRef, 
                                                                          getFieldName(parameter.Name));

        if(parameter.ParameterType.IsByRef && !parameter.IsOut)
            fieldExpression = new CodeDirectionExpression(FieldDirection.Ref, fieldExpression);
        else if(parameter.IsOut)
            fieldExpression = new CodeDirectionExpression(FieldDirection.Out, fieldExpression);
        else if(parameter.IsIn)
           fieldExpression = new CodeDirectionExpression(FieldDirection.In, fieldExpression);

        invokeExpr.Parameters.Add(fieldExpression);
    }

    wrapperType.Members.Add(callMethod);

    if(returnValue != typeof(void))
        callMethod.Statements.Add(new CodeAssignStatement(new CodeFieldReferenceExpression(thisRef,
                                                                                           getFieldName(resultPropertyName)),
                                                                                                        invokeExpr));
    else
        callMethod.Statements.Add(invokeExpr);

    codeNameSpace.Types.Add(wrapperType);

    return wrapperType;
}
```

Comment: wow thanks! this needs to be examined a little... one thing is that i cannot use .net 4 (cannot use the dynamic keyword).

Comment: Then you have to get a method info of the "CallMethod" method and invoke that. The properties can be set/read via the propertygrid. you can create a form with a propertygrid in linqpad as well, just so that you can mess with it until you understood how it all works.

Answer (score 2):

I think you could add a new class to your project that implement the `ICustomTypeDescriptor` interface. And use the instance of this class as the wrapper of your method parameters.

Here is an [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tabs/customizingcollectiondata.aspx) shows how to custom property grid display by implementing `ICustomTypeDescriptor`.

Comment: i already accepted but it still says 0%. thanks for notifying me about this.

Comment: My problem is how do i create at runtime a new object that has properties for each of the method arguments?

Comment: You could use the `ICustomTypeDescriptor` interface to control what's are shown in pgrid. You don't need to create an object with those properties. That is why `ICustomTypeDescriptor` is there. Please read the article.